# Como abrir uma caixa de diálogo para buscar um arquivo no Android? Um FileDialog

Tags: java, android

Minha dúvida é sobre abrir arquivos na minha aplicação Android, como carregar imagem do celular para o servidor onde primeiro preciso escolher a imagem no meu celular. Gostaria de saber o que preciso usar para abrir um `FileDialog`, como no C# se não me engano, no Android para escolher um arquivo de imagem ou texto que seja e carregue​ ele na minha aplicação para que eu possa trabalhar com ele (Enviar, Modificar enfim).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar esse código que vai retornar a URI da imagem selecionada pelo Picker. Depois você pode usar essa Uri para carregar a imagem ou enviá-la para outro lugar.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE);
```

Comment: Cara, sensacional, não pensei que fosse tão simples. O Interessante aqui é que posso restringir os usuários de escolherem somente os tipos de arquivos que eu quiser. Por Exemplo: `intent.setType("text/*");` para arquivos .txt ou `intent.setType("*/*");` para todos os aquivos